# How do I properly send __RequestVerificationToken with an ajax request in MVC5

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to send an ASP.NET AJAX request to my application. In the application's controller, I have:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit([Bind(Include = "ID,Name,Instructions,Glass,Notes")] Drink drink,
    [Bind(Include= "ID,Amount,Brand,IngredientID,DrinkID")] IEnumerable<DrinkIngredient> DrinkIngredients)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
//and so on
```

my javascript looks like this:

```
console.log($('#editDrinkForm').serialize())
var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
x = $.post(window.location,
    {
        data: $('#editDrinkForm').serialize()
    })
.done(function () {
    console.log("done");
})
.fail(function () {
    console.log(x.responseText);
})
```

and yet, I'm seeing this output:
[image: is too!]

You'll notice that `__RequestVerificationToken` is the first value! So what gives?

## everything else

output transcription (from a later run)

```
"__RequestVerificationToken=ZxW-JtClcOb-vYXDarYGYAEXtY84LzeiigiOKRhg4-sLSd1ixS4rwPtU-prisQ_D_vmoOYKP6cZ38ZTn5lhyg8Sh7V_F2VOgve6FkGNDOWcJy8JL8tEwPS7gy8uPd6Xl1_K8VdmWh6UGJBp372w8_w2&ID=1&Name=7%267&DrinkIngredients.index=3&DrinkIngredients%5B3%5D.ID=3&DrinkIngredients%5B3%5D.DrinkID=1&DrinkIngredients%5B3%5D.DrinkIngredientID=3&DrinkIngredients%5B3%5D.Brand=Seagram's+7+crown&DrinkIngredients%5B3%5D.ingredientID=2&DrinkIngredients%5B3%5D.Amount=1+part&DeleteDrinkIngredients.index=3&DrinkIngredients.index=4&DrinkIngredients%5B4%5D.ID=4&DrinkIngredients%5B4%5D.DrinkID=1&DrinkIngredients%5B4%5D.DrinkIngredientID=4&DrinkIngredients%5B4%5D.Brand=7-up&DrinkIngredients%5B4%5D.ingredientID=1&DrinkIngredients%5B4%5D.Amount=4+parts&DeleteDrinkIngredients.index=4&Instructions=combine%2C+stir&Glass=&Notes=fff"
```

(and)

```
"<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>

        <title>The required anti-forgery form field &quot;__RequestVerificationToken&quot; is not present.</title>

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

        <style>

         body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;} 

         p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}

         b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}

         H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }

         H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }

         pre {font-family:"Consolas","Lucida Console",Monospace;font-size:11pt;margin:0;padding:0.5em;line-height:14pt}

         .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}

         .version {color: gray;}

         .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}

         .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:"[…]
```

Comment: If you have included `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` in the view (which generates a hidden input), then its included form data (and if it wasn't, you would never hit the controller method because its decorated with `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]`). What do you mean by _"How do I properly send __RequestVerificationToken"_?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Look at the image. The unhighlighted block is the console output from the javascript that outputs the data I'm posting with the ajax request.

Comment: Yes, and the first name/value pair is for `__RequestVerificationToken=xxx` which is correct. What are you expecting?

Comment: Please add the errors to your question rather than putting relying on an image

Comment: When you have this type of problem, include *all* relevant code.  Please include the cshtml from the form start to the form end, include the controller method (with attributes), include the actual generated html.

Comment: @ErikPhilips updated again

Comment: Works fine for me (although I used just `$.post('/Test/Index', $('form').serialize(), function (data) { console.log('OK'); });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x = $.post(window.location, {data: $('#editDrinkForm').serialize()})
```

is wrong. Do this:

```
x = $.post(window.location, data: $('#editDrinkForm').serialize())
```

(some credit to stephen's comment)